# How would you limit the number of records to process per grouped key in spark? (for skewed data)

Tags: apache-spark

I have two large datasets. There are multiple groupings of the same ids. Each group has a score. I'm trying to broadcast the score to each id in each group. But I have a nice constraint that I don't care about groups with more than 1000 ids.

Unfortunately, Spark keeps reading the full grouping. I can't seem to figure out a way to push down the limit so that Spark only reads up to 1000 records, and if there are any more gives up.

So far I've tried this:

```
def run: Unit = {
    // ...

    val scores: RDD[(GroupId, Score)] = readScores(...)
    val data: RDD[(GroupId, Id)] = readData(...)

    val idToScore: RDD[(Id, Score)] = scores.cogroup(data)
      .flatMap(maxIdsPerGroupFilter(1000))

    // ...
}

def maxIdsPerGroupFilter(maxIds: Int)(t: (GroupId, (Iterable[Score], Iterable[Id]))): Iterator[(Id, Score)] = {
  t match {
    case (groupId: GroupId, (scores: Iterable[Score], ids: Iterable[Id])) =>
      if (!scores.iterator.hasNext) {
        return Iterator.empty
      }
      val score: Score = scores.iterator.next()
      val iter = ids.iterator

      val uniqueIds: mutable.HashSet[Id] = new mutable.HashSet[Id]
      while (iter.hasNext) {
        uniqueIds.add(iter.next())
        if (uniqueIds.size > maxIds) {
          return Iterator.empty
        }
      }
      uniqueIds.map((_, score)).iterator
  }
}
```

(Even with variants where the filter function just returns empty iterators, Spark still is insistent on reading all the data)

The side effect of this is that because some groups have too many ids, I have a lot of skew in the data and the job can never finish when processing the full scale of data.

I want the reduce-side to only read in the data it needs, and not crap out because of data skew.

I have a feeling that somehow I need to create a transform that is able to push down a limit or take clause, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we just filter out those groups which have records more than 1k using count() in grouped data?

or if you want to have those groups also which have more than 1k records but only to pick upto 1k records then in spark sql query you can use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY someColumn DESC) AS rn  and then put condition  rn<=1000.